# Process running in background got killed in linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, background-process

I am having a remote server to which i connect using ssh. I started a process(mongodb) on the server using following command-
"/usr/bin/mongod --dbpath /mnt/ebs-300/mongodb --logpath /mnt/ebs-300/log/mongodb/mongodb.log run --config /etc/mongodb.conf &"

As '&' is appended to the command this process runs in the background. After running the process and checking its working properly i exit from the teminal(ssh).
This process got killed after some time by printing the below logs -
"got kill or ctrl c or hup signal 1 (Hangup), will terminate after current cmd ends"

Can some one please guide me if I am doing wrong or there is proper way to run the process from the remote terminal.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try with `--fork` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that although '&' runs the command in background, when you exit your terminal it is still getting sent SIGHUP. You could use the [disown](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Egsf/man/man1/disown.html) command

> disown prevents the current shell from sending a HUP signal to each of the given jobs when the current shell terminates a login session.
>
> If job is omitted, the most recently started or stopped background job is used.

Comment: Thanks Rory for the reply. As I don't know much about linux process I need to clear a doubt that according to you even when i exit the terminal it is still getting SIGHUP which is killing the process.
To avoid this you said to use disown that ok, but can i also handle this case by using 'nohup' i.e. i would run the process like _
"nohup /usr/bin/mongod --dbpath /mnt/ebs-300/mongodb --logpath /mnt/ebs-300/log/mongodb/mongodb.log run --config /etc/mongodb.conf > /dev/null &"
Will it work ?

Comment: The '&' should be all you need for a nohup (it is equivalent), but it can still be killed if the terminal exits.

Answer (score 1):

Rory's answer is fine, but adding the `--fork` flag to your `mongod` invocation will keep it running in the background as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what nohup is for!

If it exists on your distribution, it's the simple way, plus it lets you keep a logfile.